# Combining SQL queries into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these `SQL` queries:

```
select count(*) as count1, sum(amount) as amount1 from v_purchase where amount >= 100 and 
amount <  100000 and p_date = '2014-06-12'

select count(*) as count1, sum(amount) as amount1 from v_purchase where amount >= 100000 and amount <  250000 and p_date = '2014-06-12'

select count(*) as count1, sum(amount) as amount1 from v_purchase where amount >= 250000 and amount <  500000 and p_date = '2014-06-12'

select count(*) as count1, sum(amount) as amount1 from v_purchase where amount >= 500000 and amount <  1000000 and p_date = '2014-06-12'

select count(*) as count1, sum(amount) as amount1 from v_purchase where amount >= 1000000 and amount <  2500000 and p_date = '2014-06-12'

select count(*) as count1, sum(amount) as amount1 from v_purchase where amount >= 2500000 and amount <  5000000 and p_date = '2014-06-12'

select count(*) as count1, sum(amount) as amount1 from v_purchase where amount >= 5000000 and amount <  10000000 and p_date = '2014-06-12'

select count(*) as count1, sum(amount) as amount1 from v_purchase where amount >= 10000000  p_date = '2014-06-12'
```

Is there a way of combining these queries into one and execute it as a single query? The results can then be later separated in a code.

Comment: I guess the `store procedure` will help here. Use `p_date` as parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**
Update based on discussion for a range of dates. I have created a [SQL Fiddle for you](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/98989/5)

```
    select  
        SUM(Case When amount >= 100 and amount <  100000 Then 1 else 0 End) as band1Count,
        SUM(Case When amount >= 100000 and amount <  250000 Then 1 else 0 End) as band2Count,
        SUM(Case When amount >= 250000 and amount <  500000 Then 1 else 0 End) as band3Count,
        SUM(Case When amount >= 500000 and amount <  1000000 Then 1 else 0 End) as band4Count,
        SUM(Case When amount >= 1000000 and amount <  2500000 Then 1 else 0 End) as band5Count,
       ...

        SUM(Case When amount >= 100 and amount <  100000 Then amount else 0 End) as band1Sum,
        SUM(Case When amount >= 100000 and amount <  250000 Then amount else 0 End) as band2Sum,
        SUM(Case When amount >= 250000 and amount <  500000 Then amount else 0 End) as band3Sum,
        SUM(Case When amount >= 500000 and amount <  1000000 Then amount else 0 End) as band4Sum,
        SUM(Case When amount >= 1000000 and amount <  2500000 Then amount else 0 End) as band5Sum,
       ...

    from v_purchase 
    where p_date between '2014-06-10' and '2014-06-12'
```

---

Comment: notice different sums... one is summing 1/0 for a count. The other is summing amounts

Comment: Which of `CASE` and `UNION` will have performance gains? Both seem to solve the problem.

Comment: @UchennaNwanyanwu My expectation is this will work faster. This is selecting data from the table ONCE with a single aggregation but then doing multiple functions. The UNIONS method is completing seperate select statements from the v_purchase table and slapping them together in a big kebab, which means going to disk for the data from each indivdual statement. IMHO this method causes the DB to do less work. The best way of confirming this is to turn the Actual Expecution plan on in Query Analyzer and comparing the Cost with each.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. You grouped on `p_date`, what if I am doing something like `where p_date between '2014-06-10' and '2014-06-12'`. Should I still group on `p_date`?

Comment: @UchennaNwanyanwu there also maybe scope to improve whis by adding an index to amount (possibly clustered) and also on p_date.

Comment: You didn't answer the question in my comment. Please can you answer the question?

Comment: @UchennaNwanyanwu I grouped on p_date as it was constant for all your individual queries. So, if your between clause also applies to all bands then you can continue to use it in the same way. If it doesn't you would have to incorporate the dates into each individual Case statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55492/discussion-between-sarin-and-uchenna-nwanyanwu).

Answer (score 2):

Write `UNION` keyword between those queries.

Comment: What happens if there are save values for `count1`? Are you going to combine them?

Comment: @zhongxiao37 From the query, there will always be one record for each of the queries.

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH Segments AS
(
    SELECT 100 AS MinAmount, 100000  As MaxAmount
    UNION ALL SELECT 100000, 250000 
    UNION ALL SELECT 250000, 500000 
    -- etc
)
SELECT
    Segments.MinAmount,
    Segments.MaxAmount,
    COUNT(*) AS [Count],
    SUM(v_purchase.amount) AS [Sum]
FROM
    v_purchase
    INNER JOIN Segments
        ON Segments.MinAmount <= v_purchase.amount
        AND Segments.MaxAmount > v_purchase.amount
WHERE
    v_purchase.p_date = '2014-06-12'
GROUP BY
    Segments.MinAmount,
    Segments.MaxAmount
ORDER BY
    Segments.MinAmount
```

Comment: How does this join condition work, when you're selecting the summed value (which is to be segmented) while you join on Segments.XXXAmount <= or > the amount (non-summed) ?

Comment: Every purchase is joined to it's corresponding "segment", then these results are counted and summed per segment.

Comment: @JanVanHerck +1 for cleaner solution than mine, interesting to see how it compares performance wise.

Answer (score 1):

Use the keywords "UNION ALL" between your queries. This will work if all of your columns are the same between queries.

Comment: It works but I wonder how to distinguish the result... Which one is the result for 1st query?

Comment: Add an extra column in each of your sub queries called "type" for example. Supply the value you want for each query

Comment: @Bobby You just hit the nail at the head.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you want your results horizontally or vertically.

If you want 1 row, per result, you'll need to put a category label on each row to discern between them.

```
DECLARE @p_date DATETIME = '2014-06-12'

SELECT '100 => 100000' AS Category, count(*) AS count1, SUM(amount) AS amount1 FROM v_purchase WHERE amount >= 100 AND amount <  100000 AND p_date = @p_date
UNION
SELECT '100000 => 2500000' AS Category, count(*) AS count1, SUM(amount) AS amount1 FROM v_purchase WHERE amount >= 100000 AND amount <  250000 AND p_date = @p_date
UNION
SELECT '250000 => 500000' AS Category, count(*) AS count1, SUM(amount) AS amount1 FROM v_purchase WHERE amount >= 250000 AND amount <  500000 AND p_date = @p_date
UNION
SELECT '500000 => 1000000' AS Category, count(*) AS count1, SUM(amount) AS amount1 FROM v_purchase WHERE amount >= 500000 AND amount <  1000000 AND p_date = @p_date
UNION
SELECT '1000000 => 2500000' AS Category, count(*) AS count1, SUM(amount) AS amount1 FROM v_purchase WHERE amount >= 1000000 AND amount <  2500000 AND p_date = @p_date
UNION
SELECT '2500000 => 5000000' AS Category, count(*) AS count1, SUM(amount) AS amount1 FROM v_purchase WHERE amount >= 2500000 AND amount <  5000000 AND p_date = @p_date
UNION
SELECT '5000000 => 10000000' AS Category, count(*) AS count1, SUM(amount) AS amount1 FROM v_purchase WHERE amount >= 5000000 AND amount <  10000000 AND p_date = @p_date
UNION
SELECT '> 10000000 ' AS Category, count(*) AS count1, SUM(amount) AS amount1 FROM v_purchase WHERE amount >= 10000000 AND p_date = @p_date
```

If you want all the results on a single row, then a "CASE WHEN THEN" statement would allow you to tally them up.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @ids table(idx int identity(1,1), min_amount int, max_amount int)
declare @results table(min_amount int, max_amount int, count1 int, amount1 int)

insert into @ids (min_amount, max_amount)
    select 100, 100000 union
    select 100000, 250000 union
    select 250000, 500000 union
    select 500000, 1000000 union
    select 1000000, 2500000 union
    select 2500000, 5000000 union
    select 5000000, 10000000 union
    select 10000000, 99999999

declare @i int
declare @cnt int
declare @min_amount int
declare @max_amount int

select @i = min(idx) - 1, @cnt = max(idx) from @ids

while @i < @cnt
begin
    select @i = @i + 1

    select @min_amount = min_amount from @ids where idx = @i
    select @max_amount = max_amount from @ids where idx = @i

    insert into @results(min_amount, max_amount, count1, amount1)
    select
    @min_amount,
    @max_amount,
    count(*) as count1,
    sum(amount) as amount1 
    from v_purchase
    where amount >= @min_amount and amount < @max_amount and p_date = '2014-06-12'
end

select min_amount, max_amount, count1, amount1
from @results
order by min_amount asc
```